# Android ArrayList method not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my method parsing XML, I'm having two errors showing up and I'm quite new to Android and struggling to understand what they mean, even googled with not many solutions that help.

The line

```
animals = new ArrayList();
```

Is showing - Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList

and the line

```
printAnimals(animals);
```

is showing  - The method printAnimals() in the type AnimalList is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

Below is the full method for reference

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
{
    ArrayList<Animal> animals = null;
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Animal currentAnimal = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        String name = null;
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                animals = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name == "animal")
                {
                    currentAnimal = new Animal();
                } 
                else if (currentAnimal != null)
                {
                    if (name == "specificLocation")
                    {
                        currentAnimal.specificLocation = parser.nextText();
                    } 
                    else if (name == "name"){
                        currentAnimal.name = parser.nextText();
                    } 
                    else if (name == "location")
                    {
                        currentAnimal.location= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name == "image")
                    {
                        currentAnimal.image= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name == "animalInfo")
                    {
                        currentAnimal.animalInfo= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                    else if (name == "todaysFeed")
                    {
                        currentAnimal.todaysFeed= parser.nextText();
                    }  
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("animal") && currentAnimal != null){
                    animals.add(currentAnimal);
                } 
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    printAnimals(animals);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try this way : animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried declaring your ArrayList with a type ?

```
animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Comment: animals cannot be resolved to a variable? What variable do I set it as and private or public?

Comment: I did ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>(); but Ive still got the same error for animals = new ArrayList();